# Port forward non-HTTP data on Codespaces

Tags: server, codespaces, github-codespaces

I'm trying to run a game server on GitHub Codespaces, partially to test if I can make a game server to run on Codespaces for testing purposes. When selecting how to forward a port, the only options I am given for protocol are `HTTP` and `HTTPS`, neither of which are even remotely suitable for arbitrary TCP data (specifically, it seems like nginx isn't expecting it and returns an error page).

Is there any workaround for this? Alternatively, is there any chance this is a planned feature?

Comment: A possible workaround would be to install something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) on the Codespace container

Comment: @Smitop Good idea; I may have to consider that.

Answer (score 0):

This limitation only exists for web, if you use VSCode, you can send arbitrary TCP data.

Comment: This sounds like I'm just hosting a local server, which is specifically what I can't do.